# How to link existing Parse User via FacebookUtil

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server, pfuser, pffacebookutils

I had tried a lot to achieve link existing parse user to Facebook.

I'm using swift 3.

But I can't find solution

My Status is

1. I have already account not linked Facebook.
2. I want link my account via facebookUtils
3. My app has "Sign In or SignUp Facebook" Button
4. It working like below

My problem is

1. I didn't login when I tapped Facebook login button. It means I has no PFUser.current()

Here is what I'm trying to do

1. get email address via facebookGraph API and check isUser or not via query for email
2. I had tried login like this

try! PFUser.logIn(withUsername: userObj.username!, password: userObj.password!)

but It is not working because I can't get password. It always returned nil

3. I had tried link PFUser Object which I had get via 1 query results
4. I also had tried cloud function like this

Parse.Cloud.define("fblink", function(request, response) {

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);

query.first({
  success: function(object) {

       if (!Parse.FacebookUtils.isLinked(object)) {
              Parse.FacebookUtils.link(object, null, {
                success: function(user) {
                  alert("Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
                    response.success(true);   
                },
                error: function(user, error) {
                  alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
                    response.success(false);   
                }
              });
            }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

});

But It is not working...I think cloud function approach is not a solution in this case.

I had found a lot of questions related merging exist user to Facebook authdata. But I can't find any solution.

I hope find good way together.

```
func fbBtnTapped() {

        //Show Activity indicator
        let spiningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        spiningActivity?.labelText = "Loading"
        spiningActivity?.detailsLabelText = "Please Wait"


        let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]


        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions, block: {(user:PFUser?, error:Error?) -> Void in

            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

                } else {
                    print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                }
            } else {
                print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")

            }


            if(error != nil)
            {
                spiningActivity?.hide(true)

                print("in FBBUTTONTapped Error")
                // display an error message
                let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

                myAlert.addAction(okAction)

                self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }

            // Load facebook details like userName, email address, profile picture.
            self.loadFacebookUserDetails()


        })



    }
```

Here is what I had tried in loadFacebookUserDetails.

```
func loadFacebookUserDetails()
    {
        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.view, animated: true)

        //Show Activity indicator
        let spiningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        spiningActivity?.labelText = "Loading"
        spiningActivity?.detailsLabelText = "Wait"


        //Define fields we would like to read from Facebook User Object
        let requestParameters = ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name"]
        // me
        let userDetails : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: requestParameters)

        userDetails.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {


                print("in FBDetailed Error")
                //Display error message
                spiningActivity?.hide(true)

                let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

                myAlert.addAction(okAction)

                self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                PFUser.logOut()

                return

            }

            var userId = String()
            var userName = String()
            var userEmail = String()
            var userFirstName = String()
            var userLastName = String()
            var displayName = String()

            var userObj = PFUser()

            //Extract user fields
            if let dict = result as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                userId = dict["id"] as! String
                print("User id=\(userId)")
                userEmail = (dict["email"] as? String)!
                print("User email=\(userEmail)")

                userFirstName = dict["first_name"] as! String
                print("User FirstName=\(userFirstName)")
                userLastName = dict["last_name"] as! String
                print("User LastName=\(userLastName)")
            }

            //get Username
            if !userEmail.isEmpty
            {
                PFUser.current()?.email = userEmail
                if let range = userEmail.range(of: "@") {

                    let username = userEmail.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
                    userName = username

                    PFUser.current()?.username = username
                }
            }

            PFFacebookUtils.linkUser(inBackground: PFUser.current()!, with: FBSDKAccessToken.current())


            //Get Facebook profile picture
            let userProfile = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large"

            let profilePictureUrl = URL(string:userProfile)
            let profilePictureData = try? Data(contentsOf: profilePictureUrl!)

            //Prepare PFUser object
            if(profilePictureData != nil)
            {
                let profileFileObject = PFFile(data:profilePictureData!)

                //                userObj.setObject(profileFileObject!, forKey: "profileImg")

                if (PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "profileImg")) == nil{

                    PFUser.current()?.setObject(profileFileObject!, forKey: "profileImg")
                }
            }

            displayName=userFirstName+userLastName
            PFUser.current()?.setObject(displayName, forKey: "displayname")



            //Check If user has already signedup or not
            let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
            query.whereKey("username", equalTo: userName)
            try! userObj = query.getFirstObject() as! PFUser

//            if userObj.username != nil {
//                
//                print("already signed up")
//                return
//            }
//            print(FBSDKAccessToken.current())



//            try! PFUser.logIn(withUsername: userObj.username!, password: userObj.password!)

            PFFacebookUtils.linkUser(inBackground: PFUser.current()!, with: FBSDKAccessToken.current())


//            userObj.setObject(displayName, forKey: "displayname")

            PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground(block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) in
                spiningActivity?.hide(true)

                if(error != nil)
                {
                    let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert2", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

                    myAlert.addAction(okAction)

                    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    PFUser.logOut()
                    return
                }

                if(success)
                {
                    if !userId.isEmpty
                    {
                        print(userId)
                        //userId->userName
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(userName, forKey: "username")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

                            appDelegate.buildUserInterface()
                        }

                    }

                }
            })
//



        })



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to link the account you will need `PFUser.current()` if he is not a Facebook linked account. Your options are:

1:) Logs in with facebook via the login page with your logic. This means that you have a new user in the `Users` column. So essentially that can be used as a `parse` login regardless later.  You can just update the username with maybe email or facebook name ( because facebook login will fill the username with the `ID` by default ).  Once he gets to the success page, you can ask him to fill in a password for later if he chooses to not use his facebook account in future. Then he is welcome to unlink the account in settings page with a unlink button.

```
@IBAction func unlinkFacebook(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let user = PFUser.current()
    showHUD(message: "unlinking")
    PFFacebookUtils.unlinkUser(inBackground: user!, block:{
        (succeeded: Bool?, error) -> Void in
        if succeeded! {
            self.simpleAlert(mess: "Your account is no longer associated with your Facebook account.")
            self.hideHUD()

        }else{
            self.simpleAlert(mess: "\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            self.hideHUD()
        }
    })
}
```

all the unlinking will do is clear the `authData` column.

2:) Logs in as a parse user, once successfully logged in ask him to  link his account to facebook.  a `func` maybe like:

```
func linkFacebook() {
   let user = PFUser.current()
    showHUD(message: "linking")
    if !PFFacebookUtils.isLinked(with: user!) {
        PFFacebookUtils.linkUser(inBackground:  user!, withReadPermissions: nil, block:{
            (succeeded: Bool?, error) -> Void in
            if succeeded! {
             self.simpleAlert(mess: "Success. You can now log in using your facebook account in future.")
             self.hideHUD()
            }else{
             self.simpleAlert(mess: "\(error!.localizedDescription)")
             self.hideHUD()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Could put that in your `viewdidLoad` or a nice button that gives the user a choice if he chooses to want to link his account. bare in mind you will need to call the Facebook `sdk` to update the user details if you want to store the Facebook details.

Only column that is populated in the `Users table` is `authData`.

Comment: Thanks It helps me a lot! Your solution works perfect.